# ios only app crashes coming from background

Tags: ios, flutter, fluttermap

i have a flutter app with the following:

ios: 16.6

dependencies:
bloc: ^8.1.2
crypto: ^3.0.3
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
device_info_plus: ^9.0.3
dio: ^5.3.2
encrypt: ^5.0.1
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
flutter_map: ^4.0.0
flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
geolocator: ^9.0.2
get_it: ^7.6.0
intl: ^0.18.1
latlong2: ^0.8.0
package_info_plus: ^4.1.0
pretty_dio_logger: ^1.3.1
shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
flutter_map_tile_caching: ^8.0.0
flutter_compass: '^0.7.0'
cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
local_auth: ^2.1.6

app crashes coming from background with the following error

Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

the crash log from iphone is the following

```
Incident Identifier: 42BAA013-423A-4147-894E-DD03D4FA5F52
CrashReporter Key:   36f5b4b09334eb3564b1078f6dcbb81d4a00e529
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,6
Process:             Runner [16034]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2A7926A-EB05-4EDC-B581-2ECC618A0DB7/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.app.ss
Version:             6.5.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                unknown
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.app.ss[1056]

Date/Time:           2023-08-14 13:31:57.9425 +0300
Launch Time:         2023-08-14 13:31:40.7082 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.6 (20G75)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.03.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: RUNNINGBOARD 3735883980 

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2ef2ca4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2f05b74 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2f05e4c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2ef31e8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a3fac024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a3fad250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1a3fb23ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   GraphicsServices                       0x1df4c835c GSEventRunModal + 164
8   UIKitCore                              0x1a633ef58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9   UIKitCore                              0x1a633ebbc UIApplicationMain + 340
10  Runner                                 0x102ce993c main + 64
11  dyld                                   0x1c34e4dec start + 2220
```

thank you for any insight

Comment: Yes, I found it, it was a file lock, most probably you have the same somewhere, if Can’t fix your then please provide some more details and I will be happy to help